# Change audio source in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm trying to code a music player in Vaadin. I'm using its built in Audio component.

The way I want this to work is that I select a file in a tree and it plays that audio file.

I set the correct source file in my tree handler:

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
    FilesystemContainer container = new FilesystemContainer(file);
    tree.setContainerDataSource(container);
    tree.setImmediate(true);
    mainWindow.addComponent(tree);

tree.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

            System.out.println(event);
            File file = (File) event.getProperty().getValue();
            FileResource resource = new FileResource(file, application);
            audio.setSource(resource);
            audio.pause();
            audio.requestRepaint();
        }
    });
```

However, I must refresh the page manually for this to work. How can I make the audio component pick up the new source without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a limitation of the HTML5 audio-element or the browser in question.

As a workaround you can try to remove and add a new audio component. This is very light-weight operation and should not cause any additional overhead.

Comment: Sorry, I refined the workaround approach a bit. What I see important here is that the DOM tree actually changes and I'm not sure if the re-adding (the same) component really does that. Creating a new audio component definitely does this. If not already, try this out. At least this should, it tell you something about the cause.